# I have installed Java JDK10 , I have double checked in my program files that it is installed , but command promt won't run "javac"

Tags: java

I have installed Java JDK10 , I have double checked in my program files that it is installed , but command promt won't run "javac".

When I try run "javac" it returns this error. 
`'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

But when I do `set "path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10\bin"`
and then run 'javac' **It works!**.
After that if I close cmd and reopen it, it still doesnt work!

Any ideas?

Comment: set java_home in your environement variables

Comment: add jdk bin to path environment variable via UI not in command prompt.

Comment: @tung Java makes no use of JAVA_HOME. Tomcat and some IDEs do.